# Время загрузки Windows достигло 20 минут и продолжает расти

Tags: windows, windows-10

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Время загрузки Windows-10 Домашняя на ноутбуке Xiaomi TM1701 с процессором i7 и 16 Гб оперативной памяти достигло 20 минут и продолжает расти. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно решить данную проблему?

[image: Прилагаю скрин журнала Windows]

Comment: приложите скриншоты того что у вас есть в автозагрузке. лучше воспользоваться соответствующей программой (https://ichip.ru/sovety/ekspluataciya/kak-prosmotret-programmy-v-avtozagruzke-windows-10-esli-zablokirovan-dispetcher-zadach-715422)

Что для вас долгая загрузка ? когда показывается рабочий стол, или запускается какая-то программа?

Comment: переустановите windows

Comment: Время загрузки Windows - от включения до появления формы ввода пароля пользователя. Скрин автозагрузки приложил. Версия операционной системы 19041.vb_release.191206-1406

Comment: Что написано в закладке "подробности", если выделить строку "предупреждение ⚠"?

Comment: param1 application-specific 
  param2 Local 
  param3 Activation 
  param4 {6B3C8D23-FA8D-42B9-8DBD-B950333E2E52} 
  param5 {4839CFB7-28C2-48F5-8283-E1D1807D0E7E} 
  param6 NT AUTHORITY 
  param7 LOCAL SERVICE 
  param8 S-1-5-19 
  param9 LocalHost (Using LRPC) 
  param10 Unavailable 
  param11 Unavailable

Comment: Если реально 20 минут - я бы на всякий случай взял бы `MHDD` и посмотрел бы им всё поверхность винта. Чтобы ты потом не создавал новых вопросов типа "у меня комп не грузится, как вытащить файлы?"